# Trying to solve exercise about Euler method

Tags: numerical-methods, initial-value-problems, eulers-method

Help to solve this exercise with Euler Method, my problem here problem is that the solutions I calculated are not close to the real values and they diverge. Thanks!

$$y'=e^y $$

with conditions $$ 0\leq t\leq0.2,  y(0)=1$$

**First of all, my solution** for the ecd was $$y(t)=ln{\frac{e}{1-et}}$$
then for the Euler Method, I used h=0.02, We have the first iteration

$$f(t_i,y_i)=e^y$$
$$y_{i+1}=y_i+f(t_i,y_i)h$$
$$y(0.02)=1+e^{(1)}(0.02)=1.05436$$

| t_i | y_real | y_euler |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0.02 | 0.9456 | 1.05436 |
| 0.04 | 0.8912 | 1.11177 |
| 0.06 | 0.8369 | 1.17257 |
| 0.08 | 0.7825 | 1.23717 |
| 0.1 | 0.7281 | 1.30609 |
| 0.12 | 0.6738 | 1.37993 |
| 0.14 | 0.6194 | 1.45942 |
| 0.16 | 0.565 | 1.54549 |
| 0.18 | 0.5107 | 1.63929 |
| 0.2 | 0.4563 | 1.74233 |

Comment: What is $y_{real}$? If you plug $0.02$ into $\ln\frac{e}{1-et}$ you should get $1.0618$, a number greater than $1$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please note your $y_{\rm real}$ is not correct:

| t_i | y_real | y_euler |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0.02 | 1.0559 | 1.05436 |
| 0.04 | 1.11511 | 1.11177 |
| 0.06 | 1.17805 | 1.17257 |
| 0.08 | 1.24521 | 1.23717 |
| 0.1 | 1.31722 | 1.30609 |
| 0.12 | 1.39481 | 1.37993 |
| 0.14 | 1.47894 | 1.45942 |
| 0.16 | 1.5708 | 1.54549 |
| 0.18 | 1.67195 | 1.63929 |
| 0.2 | 1.78451 | 1.74233 |

Calculated using Mathematica:

```
Table[Log[E/(1 - E* 0.02*i)], {i, 0, 10}]
```